# Render template for HtmlResponse

Tags: 8, theming

In my controller I want to return `Drupal\Core\Render\HtmlResponse`, and also I want to take HTML content from the template. The problem is that if I will try to `render()` a rendereable array before returning HtmlResponse - I'm getting `"The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."` error. Array is being rendered correctly when I will just return it as it is, but with all Drupal HTML, which I don't want. What am I doing wrong?

**Added #1:** Discovery - all works well when I return `Zend\Diactoros\Response\HtmlResponse` . Now I'm even more confused. Why is that?

**Added #2:** When I use "renderPlain()" renderers method it also works, but I'm not sure of drawbacks yet.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I believe I should use "renderRoot()" method of renderer in case where I'm rendering HTML for response just to be send. Please correct me someone if I'm wrong.